# I meesed up. How to clean repo? Can't normally update

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, repository

so, i'm newbie in ubuntu server. So, done this done that, and now, when I run `sudo apt update`, getting this message:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/d.../dists/squeeze/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 108.157.214.62 80]
E: The repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/d... squeeze InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to clean this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Next time, please add more context than ", done this done that, and now". I did manage to track down the command you ran, from https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/docs-developer-install-ubuntu.aspx this one here:

```bash
echo "deb https://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onlyoffice.list
```

If you **don't** want to continue with the OnlyOffice tutorial, let's remove the repo. Run this command:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onlyoffice.list
```

Ubuntu now does not attempt to pull from that repository. Let's update the repositories with apt:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

If you **do** want to continue the installation, let's go back to the step you skipped:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.gnupg
chmod 700 ~/.gnupg
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/tmp/onlyoffice.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys CB2DE8E5
chmod 644 /tmp/onlyoffice.gpg
sudo chown root:root /tmp/onlyoffice.gpg
sudo mv /tmp/onlyoffice.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

If you have issues with that step, you might be missing packages. Run:

```bash
sudo apt install gnupg gpg ca-certificates
```

Finally, update the repos with apt:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

A successful response will include this:

```
Get:5 https://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease [10.7 kB]
Get:6 https://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze/main amd64 Packages [14.6 kB]
```